# Current status of DifferentDatabaseScope implementation

Tags: castle-activerecord

my current project requires to connect to two different database (same schema, different database engine) using castle activerecord. The connection string for first database is same all the time, but the second one is changed dynamically based on user input. I decided that the best solution is to use `DifferentDatabaseScope` for second database.

From castle project documentation, it stated that `DifferentDatabaseScope` **Still very experimental and it's not bullet proof for all situations.** I want to know what are the situations that make `DifferentDatabaseScope` failed or not behave as intended.